# How to restrict the user to input only letters and numbers in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write an algorithm that validates a player's username and checks to see if the name is registered in an external text file.

```
playerName = input('Please enter a player name')
```

How do I restrict the user to only being able to enter letters and numbers?

Comment: you can use regex and if statement to check that

Comment: use `playerName.isalnum()` to check the user typed alphabets or numbers. For more details, see example - https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isalnum.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @peer said, you can use a regex in a while loop.
There is no way to do it with input command.

**Exemple of code:**

```
import re
 
playerName = '_'
    
while(not re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]*$", playerName)):
    playerName = input('Please enter a player name (Only letters and numbers)')
    
print("PlayerName: ", playerName)
```

**EDIT**

As @Joe Ferndz wrote in comment, you can use isalnum() method to check if your playerName is alphanumeric, so you don't even need to use regex

```
playerName = '_'
    
while(not playerName.isalnum()):
    playerName = input('Please enter a player name (Only letters and numbers)')
    
print("PlayerName: ", playerName)
```

Comment: playerName.isalnum() will take care of it

Comment: @JoeFerndz Thank you for me, I didnt know this method *facepalm* It will help me so much in future :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot restrict what the user can type (at least with input) but you can use a while loop to repeat the input request until user gets it right